# Block opening of TabItem in Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, wpf-controls, tabitem

I have some TabItem controls in a WPF project and I need to block them from opening when a certain event is happening. Basically I set a Boolean variable to true when the process occurs, and false when it ends and as long as the property is true, no other TabItem can be opened. My problem is why I haven't found the method that controls the opening of the TabItem. Can anyone give me a help on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a custom `TabControl` and override the `OnSelectionChanged` method:

```
public class CustomTabControl :TabControl
{
    private bool _handle = true;

    public bool IsSelectable { get; set; } = true;

    protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(IsSelectable)
        {
            base.OnSelectionChanged(e);
        }
        else if (_handle && e.RemovedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            _handle = false;
            SelectedItem = e.RemovedItems[0];
            _handle = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Set `IsSelectable` to `false`to prevent tabs from being selected:

```
<local:CustomTabControl IsSelectable="False">
    <TabItem Header="1">
        <TextBox Text="..." />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="2" >
        <TextBox Text="..." />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="3">
        <TextBox Text="..." />
    </TabItem>
</local:CustomTabControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use binding to the SelectedItem property. When it change its time to call method.